# LayoutSubviews is called after applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: ios, ipad, layoutsubviews

After some research I found that the problem occurs on all 64 bit iPads, but not iPhones.
Tested on iOS 9, 10 and 11

The strange thing is that problem does not occur on WWDC 2013 Street Scroller app.

Is this a normal behaviour or should I fill bug report at Apple?

Comment: Surprising maybe, but is it a problem?